# Error TS2554, expected argument 2 but got 1

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angularfire2

Here problem is shown in 3rd line:

```
login(myForm1) {
  if(myForm1.valid) {
    this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword({
      email: this.email,
      password: this.password
    }).then(
      (success)=>{
        this.router.navigate(['/blog']);
    }).catch(
      (err)=>{
        this.error=err;
    })
  }
}
```

So how can I solve it? I'm searching here and there but I'm don't understand properly.

Comment: It seems that `signInWithEmailAndPassword` expects two arguments (perhaps an email and password) but you only supply one argument (an object).

Answer (score 1):

You only have one argument here, an object. The function `signInWithEmailAndPassword(...)` expected to have 2 arguments. Just do this :

```
this.af.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email,this.password)
```